# Why should I use Spring Android?

Tags: java, android, spring

Anyone out here use Spring Android? If so, why do you think it's worth while?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Spring Android is useful if you need to access RESTful Web services from your Android application.  This is common in real-time data applications such as news and weather tickers, stock tickers, etc.

For now, there are two benefits to using the Spring Android project: commons logging and RestTemplate.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: is this similar to spring for java ?

Comment: im not clear whats the advantage of this 'Spring android' over just using gson with a POJO.  Could you tell me why its more flexible ?

Comment: what about the performance, I hear about some issues/slowness on Android devices

Answer (score 3):

In addition Spring Android is useful to work with HTTP Request from your Android application.
You don't need to use another Libraries like [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) because spring supports them internally.

Comment: im not sure i have the same framework. is this what im looking for: http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/