# Calling a method with using bean and reflection

Tags: java, android, spring, reflection, javabeans

I have some classes and i want declare these classes in bean xml file. I want to call methods from these classes with reflection. I mean i have two feature in bean tag, one 'id' and another 'class', I want when take id value to a methods in reflection, find class and call special method. anyway, i searched about java beans, reflection and etc but i cant use these and i want to see a simple tutorial because my knowledge is very basic and little :(

How can i use bean xml file in reflection for calling a method from special class that the class declare in bean file?

for using bean xml file, i should install spring framework? and where should i create xml file with beans tag?(i mean i should create this in special directory, like below src or below res...)

Thanks for advises

Comment: what type of project are you doing. is it maven project? is it java or java web project?

Comment: This is Android project.

Answer (score 0):

For spring web application,By default you can declare beans in

```
/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
```

You can also declare beans in someName.xml in separate folder inside   /WEB-INF/ like

```
 /WEB-INF/config/database.xml
```

which could be imported in  **/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml** or other like

```
<import resource="/WEB-INF/config/database.xml"/>
```

and register  ApplicationContext using ContextLoaderListener in web.xml as follows:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

for more information look spring docummentation.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/reference/beans.html

if you are doing android then there is spring-android library but it doesn't seems to help you.
[Why should I use Spring Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795131/why-should-i-use-spring-android)

you might need to write your bean declaration file as plain xml inside resource folder and

```
res/xml/
```

see:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html
additionally you will have to implement your logic reading beans from that xml file.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i can't use web application. I am in android application and i want use bean component (beans tag in xml file) from spring for declare all of my classes and take these classes and methods with reflection in android. Do you understand what i mean? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

From the Spring page:

Features
A Rest Client for Android
Auth support for accessing secure APIs

Spring android does not have bean configuration. Why do you need it? What you want may be done with generics and reflection. Could you provide an example of why you want that?

Comment: Thanks FcoP. I want to create a bean xml file that i set all of my classes(with my packages) and i want in id tag in bean tag, set a method name from my class. like below: (<bean id="SMS" class="org.example.sendingSMS"/>) and with this, i can get SMS method from sendingSMS class with reflection. I mean i can send method name and parameter from this method to reflection class and then call method. This is a training sample for learning android and java bean and reflection in android and then use this in real project. Thanks and sorry for my long text